# How can I apply `prop.table` on the margin of a table in r?

Tags: r, matrix

I created a table as following:

```
mymatrix3=matrix(c(29,54,44,77,62,131,36,67), nrow=4, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(mymatrix3) <- c("Right Direction", "Wrong Direction")
rownames(mymatrix3) <-c("Northeast", "North Central", "South", "West")
mymatrix3

sample_dist = as.array(prop.table(mymatrix3,2))
```

It gives me: mymatrix3 which is the opinion of people of different regions over the direction of government:

```
                   Right Direction Wrong Direction
Northeast                  29              54
North Central              44              77
South                      62             131
West                       36              67
```

sample_dist:

```
              Right Direction Wrong Direction
Northeast           0.1695906       0.1641337
North Central       0.2573099       0.2340426
South               0.3625731       0.3981763
West                0.2105263       0.2036474
```

However, what I want is the sum of two columns over the row margin of table. I don't want to separate class of people. I want to aggregate them and then calculate the prop. What can I do?

Comment: In your example are missing `r` and `c `in `mymatrix3=matrix(c(29,54,44,77,62,131,36,67), nrow=r, ncol = c, byrow = TRUE)` that I suppose are 4 and 2.

Comment: @s_t right.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum rows then calculate the table :

```
prop.table(rowSums(mymatrix3,2))

> Northeast     North Central South         West 
  0.166         0.242         0.386         0.206
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want simply the sum of rows of the columns (should work with any number of columns), what about:

```
cbind(sample_dist, total = rowSums(sample_dist))
              Right Direction Wrong Direction     total
Northeast           0.1695906       0.1641337 0.3337244
North Central       0.2573099       0.2340426 0.4913525
South               0.3625731       0.3981763 0.7607494
West                0.2105263       0.2036474 0.4141737
```

In case you need their weight on their total:

```
cbind(sample_dist, total = rowSums(sample_dist), perc = prop.table(rowSums(sample_dist)))

              Right Direction Wrong Direction     total      perc
Northeast           0.1695906       0.1641337 0.3337244 0.1668622
North Central       0.2573099       0.2340426 0.4913525 0.2456762
South               0.3625731       0.3981763 0.7607494 0.3803747
West                0.2105263       0.2036474 0.4141737 0.2070869
```

Comment: The total column has a sum greater than one

Comment: Yes it's only the sum of the two columns.

Comment: I think the question is sum then margin. Might be wrong

Comment: Ok, I might be wrong, so I updated the answer, thanks.